# How to run a method within a subclass from a superclass?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, subclass

I have two java files. The Main Activity Contains the following:

```
    String randomEvent;

    public void randomTrigger(){

        int min = 1;
        int max = 100;

        Random randomTrigger = new Random();
        int randomNumber = randomTrigger.nextInt(max - min) + min;

        RandomEvent obj = new RandomEvent();

        if (randomNumber == 7) {

            // What do I put here to call the method randomEvent(); in RandomEvent.java ?

        }


    }

    saveSettings();{
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("com.******.******", MODE_PRIVATE);
        settings.edit().putString("randomEvent", randomEvent).commit();
    }
```

The second activity called "RandomEvent.java is a subclass of MainActivity:

```
package com.******.******;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class RandomEvent extends MainActivity {

    public void randomEvent() {

        MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
        obj.randomEvent = "You've received a pay raise!";

        payRate = payRate * 1.1f;

        saveSettings();

    }
}
```

My question is, how do I properly execute the randomEvent(); method that is located in the RandomEvent.java class file from within the superclass MainActivity ?

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202432/how-to-call-method-in-main-activity-from-other-activity

Comment: If you already have obj as a RandomEvent instance ( RandomEvent obj = new RandomEvent(); ), you can simply call obj.randomEvent();

By the way, that design is not so clear. How would MainActivity now a subclass. You may implement something similar following the Template Method pattern.

Comment: Sorry if my wording isn't clear. MainActivity is the superclass of RandomEvent which extends MainActivity.

Comment: If you have to call a child class method from parent class then you need to declare the same method in parent class it's the basic concept of inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achived by doing this:-

```
public class MainActivity{
 public void randomEvent() {}  

}

public class RandomEvent extends MainActivity{
 @Override
 public void randomEvent() {
    //You stuff
 }   
}
```

In this approach, you can call the **randomEvent** from the MainActivity.
But it's better to do this in that way:-

```
public interface Events{
  public void randomEvent();
}

public abstract class MainActivity implements Events{

}

public class RandomEvent extends MainActivity{
  @Override
 public void randomEvent() {
    //You stuff
 } 
}
```

It's better if you keep your code clean in that way or what else you can do is:-

```
public interface Events{
  public void randomEvent();
}
public class MainActivity{
      public Events getEvents(){
        return null;
      }

      public void randomTrigger(){

            Events events = getEvents();
            if(null != events){
               events.randomEvent();
            }
        }


    }
    }

public class RandomEvent extends MainActivity implements Events{
  @Override
 public void randomEvent() {
    //You stuff
 }
 @Override
 public Events getEvents(){
    return this;
  } 
}
```

Best one is last one.