# how to call a function from other activity android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

In my Android app I have two activities :

1) MapsActivity
2) OtherActivity

**MapsActivity** has navigation drawer through which I opened **OtherActivity** . Now , I want to call a method (like **updatemap()** ) from **MapsActivity** .

After searching a lot on google I found this question on stackoverflow 
[How to call method in main activity from other activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202432/how-to-call-method-in-main-activity-from-other-activity)  but that doesn't solves my problem .

**UPDATE :**

Here is the code for OtherActivity :

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {.....}

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
     .... }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
     super.onStart();  
     removeConnection(userID)
     .... }

   private void removeConnection(String currentUserId) { 
     ... 
     // Here I want to call a function from MapsActivity i.e. disaplayLocation()
   }

   public static class ConnectedViewHolder extends 
   RecyclerView.ViewHolder{ ... }
}
```

Code for MapsActivity is :

```
  public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  OnMapReadyCallback,
  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
  LocationListener {

      @Override
      protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) { ... }

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ... }

      @Override
      public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull 
       String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) { ... }

      private void setUpLocation() { ... }

      public void displayLocation() { ... }  // This is the function i want to call

      private void createLocationRequest() { ... } 

      @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { ... } 

      protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() { ... } 

      private boolean checkPlayServices() { ... }

      private void requestRuntimePermission() { ... } 

      private void startLocationUpdates()  { ... }

      @Override
      public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) { ... }

      @Override
      public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) { ... }

      @Override
      public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) { ... }

      @Override
      public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult 
       connectionResult) { ... }

      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { ... }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { ... }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { ... }

      private void makeConnectionToGetLocation() { ... }

      private void updateConnectedLatLng() { ... }

  }
```

I am pasting only structure of code because it is 1000 line of code and pasting here is of no use and become more complicate to read .

I tried to add **static** keyword before displayLocation method but it gives error in variables within function and making every variable to global is not possible .

Comment: you can use static method or libraries like event bus to perform this action

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do? for example do you want update the map after an action is done?
you cant call method of other activities, event if you do you are likely to encounter error since only one activity can be active at a time.

Comment: @NagendraHariKarthick Please ,  Read updated question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MapsActivity` is expecting a result from `OtherActivity`, you're better off with [Getting Result From an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result). Simply call `OtherActivity` via `startActivityForResult()` (instead of `startActivity()`):

```
static final int MAP_REQUEST = 1;  // your request code
...
private void callOtherActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class)
    startActivityForResult(intent, MAP_REQUEST);
}
```

Then in your `MapsActivity`, do this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MAP_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            updateMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a static function in one Activity like

```
public static double getVariance(double[] data)
{
    double mean = getMean(data);
    double temp = 0;
    for(double a :data)
        temp += (mean-a)*(mean-a);
    return temp/data.length;
}
```

Then in another activity call it as:

```
double res = Activity1.getVariance(<your data>);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, you may get NullObjectRefernce if the other activity is closed.

to do it you can use `public static` method. so, you can call it from anywhere in the application.

in your activity add it.

```
public static void YOUR_NAME(){}
```

to call it in second activity add it.

```
   try{
    YOUR_ACTIVITY.YOUR_NAME();

    }catch(Exception e){}
```

another solution, you can use **EventBus** library

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus